# Check Status of Services

Tags: shell, awk

i am trying to create a script to get the Service status from different Remote servers:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=vagrant

isengine=(server1 server2 server3 server4 server5)
isengine_services=( ds.rc DFDServer ISFAgents ODFEngine)


for h in "${isengine[@]}"
do
  echo "${h}" >> test.txt
  for i in "${isengine_services[@]}"
  do
     sshpass -p "mysecret" ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  "${USERNAME}"@"${h}" "echo ${i}; systemctl status ${i} | grep Active" >> tmp.txt

  done
done

cat tmp.txt
```

I get very chaotic output that look like this:

```
server1
ds.rc
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:48 CEST; 3 days ago
DFDServer
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:05:02 CEST; 3 days ago
ISFAgents
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:46 CEST; 3 days ago
ODFEngine
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:20 CEST; 3 days ago
```

is it possible to make it look the following way:

```
server1

ds.rc       Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:48 CEST; 3 days ago
DFDServer   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:05:02 CEST; 3 days ago
ISFAgents   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:46 CEST; 3 days ago
ODFEngine   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:20 CEST; 3 days ago
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use GNU `AWK` for converting from two-liners to one-liners as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
server1
ds.rc
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:48 CEST; 3 days ago
DFDServer
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:05:02 CEST; 3 days ago
ISFAgents
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:46 CEST; 3 days ago
ODFEngine
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:20 CEST; 3 days ago
```

then

```
awk '{ORS=NR%2?"\n":" ";print}' file.txt
```

output

```
server1
ds.rc    Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:48 CEST; 3 days ago
DFDServer    Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:05:02 CEST; 3 days ago
ISFAgents    Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:46 CEST; 3 days ago
ODFEngine    Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 10:04:20 CEST; 3 days ago
```

Explanation: If number of current row (`NR`) is odd (i.e. remainder of division by 2 is non-zero) then print this line followed by newline otherwise use space (`condition?value1:value2` is `AWK`'s ternary operator, if condition is meet `value1` is used, otherwise `value2` is used). In other words join every even line and subsequent line with space between them.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

You can set services variable from this:

```
isengine_services=( ds.rc DFDServer ISFAgents ODFEngine)
```

to be this:

```
isengine_services="ds.rc DFDServer ISFAgents ODFEngine"
```

and replace the internal loop:

```
  for i in "${isengine_services[@]}"
  do
     sshpass -p "mysecret" ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  "${USERNAME}"@"${h}" "echo ${i}; systemctl status ${i} | grep Active" >> tmp.txt
  done
```

with this:

```
echo $h  >> tmp.txt
sshpass -p "mysecret" ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  "${USERNAME}"@"${h}" "systemctl status $isengine_services"  >> tmp.txt
```